# Tensorflow.js wrong path while saving (EINVAL invalid argument mkdir)

Tags: node.js, windows, tensorflow.js

I'm using @tensorflow/tfjs-node on Node v12.9.1 on Windows 10. When I try to save to a path, like this;

```
const pathModule=require('path');
const newFilename = 'model1'; // Actually, comes from another place
const completeFn = 'file:///'+pathModule.resolve(newFilename).split(pathModule.sep).join('/');
await model.save(completeFn);
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, mkdir 'C:\C:\Users\E\Desktop\ML\cnn1\model1'
```

The current path is C:\Users\E\Desktop\ML\cnn1, and when debugging I see that `completeFn` is `"file:///C:/Users/E/Desktop/ML/cnn1/model1"` (which I test on Chrome and Explorer and works fine after create the folder).

This is a bug or an undocumented feature?

My workaround is to use …`="file://"+newFilename;` (with two slashes), but I'm worried about compatibility.

Comment: I'm not sure I can follow. It's not working with `file:///` (3 slashes), but it's working with `file://` (2 slashes)? Why would you use `file:///` (3 slashes) then? The docs also only use `file://` (2 slashes).

Comment: Hi, @ThomasDondorf! Two slashes works like relative path, and three means absolute path (that's what I want). Also, the docs I'm looking[1] uses 3 slashes: `await model.save('file:///path/to/my-model');`. [1] tensorflow.org/js/guide/save_load

Comment: As documented in https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2006/12/06/file-uris-in-windows/.

Comment: I see, but Tf.js is just using the `file://` prefix to differentiate between localstore, file, http, etc. Have a look at the code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/blob/9cb4d53fa20dd58349a131c834c3054906dbb897/tfjs-node/src/io/file_system.ts#L43). Tensorflow.js will simply check if the string starts with that value and then cut the prefix off. Hope that helps you already, I'll add a more detailed answer later.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

Tensorflow.js uses the `file://` prefix to differentiate between localstore, file, http, and the other IO options ([relevant code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/blob/9cb4d53fa20dd58349a131c834c3054906dbb897/tfjs-node/src/io/file_system.ts#L43)). The library checks if the string starts with that value and then [cuts the prefix off](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/blob/9cb4d53fa20dd58349a131c834c3054906dbb897/tfjs-node/src/io/file_system.ts#L254). That means, when your script saves the model, it will not try to save it to `file:///C:/...`, but to `/C:/...` resulting in the above error.

**Solution**

To fix it, simply use the `file://C:/...` (with two slashes), which means that Tensorflow.js saves the model to `C:/...`.